# Load Menu from file

Tags: php, regex

i try to filter my menu.info file and show all items via php.

My Code:

```
// Load menu.info
        $menu_info = file_get_contents("menu.info");

        // Find Menu Items

      $re1='(<item link=")((.*))(">)((.*))(<\\/item>)'; # Tag 1

      if ($c=preg_match_all ("/".$re1."/is", $menu_info, $matches))
      {
          /*$word3=$matches[2][0]; // Link
          $word4=$matches[4][0]; // Name*/

          print_r($matches[2]);
      }
```

My menu.info

```
<menu>
    <item link="dashboard.htm">Dashboard-Test</item>
    <item link="dashboard2.htm">Dashboard-Test2</item>
    <item link="dashboard3.htm">Dashboard-Test3</item>
    <item link="dashboard4.htm">Dashboard-Test4</item>
</menu>
```

The Output of `print_r($matches[2);`:

```
            Array
(
    [0] => dashboard.htm">Dashboard-Test</item>
    <item link="dashboard2.htm">Dashboard-Test2</item>
    <item link="dashboard3.htm">Dashboard-Test3</item>
    <item link="dashboard4.htm
)
```

So i guess preg_match_all can't see there are 4  and not just 1.
I don't really know much about regex so i guess it's maybe the pattern.

I just want an array like this:

```
array(
 [0] => "Dashboard-Test",
 [1] => "Dashboard-Test2",
 [2] => "Dashboard-Test3",
 [3] => "Dashboard-Test4"
)
array(
 [0] => "dashboard.htm",
 [1] => "dashboard2.htm",
 [2] => "dashboard3.htm",
 [3] => "dashboard4.htm"
)
```

So i can use this infos to fill my Menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo :** https://eval.in/85150

```
$menu_info = '<menu>
    <item link="dashboard.htm">Dashboard-Test</item>
    <item link="dashboard2.htm">Dashboard-Test2</item>
    <item link="dashboard3.htm">Dashboard-Test3</item>
    <item link="dashboard4.htm">Dashboard-Test4</item>
</menu>';

 $re1='/(<item link=")((.*))(">)((.*))(<\/item>)/'; 

      if ($c=preg_match_all ($re1, $menu_info, $matches))
      {
          /*$word3=$matches[2][0]; // Link
          $word4=$matches[4][0]; // Name*/

          print_r($matches[5]);
          print_r($matches[2]);
       }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dashboard-Test
    [1] => Dashboard-Test2
    [2] => Dashboard-Test3
    [3] => Dashboard-Test4
)
Array
(
    [0] => dashboard.htm
    [1] => dashboard2.htm
    [2] => dashboard3.htm
    [3] => dashboard4.htm
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to parse it, use a xml parser instead.

```
$menu_info = simplexml_load_file("menu.info");
```

Comment: I want to use it in a little cms i write.

Comment: And i think some webspaces dont have simplexml